# partial lookup in key-value map where key itself is a key-value map

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

Suppose we have a data structure that is a key-value map, where the key itself is again a key-value map. For example:

```
map<map<string,string>>, string>
```

Now, suppose that we want to query all top-level key/values in this map matching a certain subset of the key-values of the key. Example:

```
map = { { "k1" : "v1", "k2 : "v2" } : "value1",
  { "k1" : "v3", "k2 : "v4" } : "value2",
  { "k1" : "v1", "k2 : "v5" } : "value3"
}
```

And our query is "give me all key-values where key contains `{ "k1" : "v1" }` and it would return the first and third value. Similarly, querying for `{ "k1" : "v3", "k2" : "v4" }` would return all key-values that have both `k1=v3` and `k2=v4`, yielding the second value. Obviously we could search through the full map on every query, but I'm looking for something more efficient than that.

I have looked around, but can't find an efficient, easy-to-use solution out there for C++. Boost multi_index does not seem to have this kind of flexibility in querying subsets of key-value pairs.

Some databases have ways to create indices that can answer exactly these kind of queries. For example, Postgres has GIN indices (generalized inverted indices) that allow you to ask

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_json_column @> '{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}'
-- returns all rows that have both k1=v1 and k2=v2
```

However, I'm looking for a solution without databases just in C++. Is there any library or data structure out there that can accomplish something like this? In case there is none, some pointers on a custom implementation?

Comment: Is writing custom code taking key-value pairs and returning pairs from the queried map out of the question?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean exactly, but it's fine if the structure is similar to eg. map<vector<pair<string,string>>, string> or even any other kind of structure that can answer the queries efficiently. Some custom code should be fine here.

Comment: You have a specific problem, but it seems like you are only looking for library recommendations . Those kind of questions are not allowed on SO. If you awnt to write the code yourself, it doesn't seem all that complicated to split the searches into 1 key-value pair and then cache the result so it can be re-used.

Comment: Apologies. I'll rephrase the question. I'm not looking specifically for a library solution, but usually on questions like this people would answer 'oh you can use library x to accomplish this'. I just found it hard to believe there wouldn't be something for this already. Some guidelines for me regarding a custom implementation would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`std::includes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) to check if key maps include another map of queried key-value pairs.
I am unsure how to avoid checking every key-map though. Maybe other answers have a better idea.

```
template <typename MapOfMapsIt, typename QueryMapIt>
std::vector<MapOfMapsIt> query_keymap_contains(
    MapOfMapsIt mom_fst,
    MapOfMapsIt mom_lst,
    QueryMapIt q_fst,
    QueryMapIt q_lst)
{
    std::vector<MapOfMapsIt> out;
    for(; mom_fst != mom_lst; ++mom_fst)
    {
        const auto key_map = mom_fst->first;
        if(std::includes(key_map.begin(), key_map.end(), q_fst, q_lst))
            out.push_back(mom_fst);
    }
    return out;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> StrMap;
typedef std::map<StrMap, std::string> MapKeyMaps;
MapKeyMaps m = {{{{"k1", "v1"}, {"k2", "v2"}}, "value1"},
                {{{"k1", "v3"}, {"k2", "v4"}}, "value2"},
                {{{"k1", "v1"}, {"k2", "v5"}}, "value3"}};
StrMap q1 = {{"k1", "v1"}};
StrMap q2 = {{"k1", "v3"}, {"k2", "v4"}};
auto res1 = query_keymap_contains(m.begin(), m.end(), q1.begin(), q1.end());
auto res2 = query_keymap_contains(m.begin(), m.end(), q2.begin(), q2.end());
std::cout << "Query1:    ";
for(auto i : res1) std::cout << i->second << " ";
std::cout << "\nQuery2:    ";
for(auto i : res2) std::cout << i->second << " ";
```

**Output:**

```
Query1:    value1 value3 
Query2:    value2
```

<kbd>[**Live Example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ads5izq0MPRZAr8U)</kbd>

Comment: Why do you have iterators for the query but not the map?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This gives a nice interface to query the map, which is useful. However, I think this piece of code is still not efficient in the sense that for every query, it still looks at the full map, basically just going through it one-by-one. Would it be possible to construct an index-like data structure for this that does not require every element to be compared for every query?

Comment: @fvannee Please take a look

Comment: @AMA You are still iterating over all `map` entries in every query. Aren't you?

Comment: @DanielLangr only checking every key-map. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @AMA I believe so, with the help of some auxiliary "index" data structure. Check my question for an exemplary solution. For instance, the query for single `"kX:vY"` pair takes _O(log(k))_, where _k_ is the number of "index" map entries (onle could use a hash table instead to reduce this complexity). Of course, we also additionally need to compare strintgs and copy results.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay with the database index analogy. In that analogy, the indexed search does not use a generic k=v type search, but just a tuple with the values for the elements (generally columns) that constitute the index. The database then reverts to scans for the other k=v parameters that are not in the index.

In that analogy, you would have a fixed number of keys that could be represented as an array or strings (fixed size). The good news is that it is then trivial to set a global order on the keys, and thanks to the `std::map::upper_bound` method, it is also trivial to find an iterator immediately after a partial key.

So getting a full key is immediate: just extract it with `find`, `at` or `operator []`. And getting all elements for a partial key is still simple:

- find an iterator starting above the partial key with `upper_bound`
- iterate forward while the element matches the partial key

But this require that you change your initial type to `std::map<std::array<string, N>, string>`

You could build an API over this container using `std::map<string, string>` as input values, extract the actual full or partial key from that, and iterate as above, keeping only elements matching the k,v pairs not present in index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with as single (partial) pass through each element with an ordered query, returning early as much as possible. Taking inspiration from [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference), we want to know if `query` is a subset of `data`, which lets us select entries of the outer map.

```
// Is the sorted range [first1, last1) a subset of the sorted range [first2, last2)
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
bool is_subset(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2)
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        if (first2 == last2) return false; // Reached the end of data with query still remaing

        if (*first1 < *first2) {
            return false; // didn't find this query element
        } else {
            if (! (*first2 < *first1)) {
                ++first1; // found this query element
            }
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    return true; // reached the end of query
}

// find every element of "map-of-maps" [first2, last2) for which the sorted range [first1, last1) is a subset of it's key
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt>
OutputIt query_data(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2, OutputIt d_first)
{
    auto item_matches = [=](auto & inner){ return is_subset(first1, last1, inner.first.begin(), inner.first.end()); };
    return std::copy_if(first2, last2, d_first, item_matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the efficiency of different methods will depend on actual data. However, I would consider making a "cache" of iterators to outer map elements for particular `"kX","vY"` pairs as follows:

```
using M = std::map<std::map<std::string, std::string>, std::string>;
M m = {
   { { { "k1", "v1" }, { "k2", "v2" } }, "value1" },
   { { { "k1", "v3" }, { "k2", "v4" } }, "value2" },
   { { { "k1", "v1" }, { "k2", "v5" } }, "value3" }
};

std::map<M::key_type::value_type, std::vector<M::iterator>> cache;
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
   for (const auto& kv : it->first)
      cache[kv].push_back(it);
```

Now, you basically need to take all searched `"kX","vY"` pairs and find the intersection of cached iterators for them:

```
std::vector<M::key_type::value_type> find_list = { { "k1", "v1" }, { "k2", "v5" } };
std::vector<M::iterator> found;
if (find_list.size() > 0) {
   auto it = find_list.begin();
   std::copy(cache[*it].begin(), cache[*it].end(), std::back_inserter(found));
   while (++it != find_list.end()) {
      const auto& temp = cache[*it];
      found.erase(std::remove_if(found.begin(), found.end(),
            [&temp](const auto& e){ return std::find(temp.begin(), temp.end(), e) == temp.end(); } ),
         found.end());
   }
}
```

The final output:

```
for (const auto& it : found)
   std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
```

gives `value3` in this case.

A live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/S9Zp8yofSvjfLokc.

---

Note that the complexity of the intersection step is quite large, since cached iterators are unsorted. If you use pointers instead, you can sort the vectors or store the pointers in a map instead, which would allow you to find intersections much faster, e.g., by using `std::set_intersection`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is implemented as a balanced binary tree which has O(nlgn) look-up. What you need instead, is `std::unordered_map` which is implemented as a hash-table, that is O(1) look-ups.

Now let me rephrase your wording, you want to:

> And our query is "give me all key-values where key contains { "k1" : "v1" } and it would return the first and third value.

Which translates to:

> If the key-value pair given is in the inner map, give me back its value. 
>    Essentially what you need is a double look-up which std::unordered_map excel at.

Here is a code spinet that solves your problem with the standard library (no fancy code required)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main() {
  using elemType = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
  using innerMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
  using myMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, innerMap>;

  auto table = myMap{ { "value1", { {"k1", "v1"}, {"k2", "v2"} } },
                      { "value2", { {"k1", "v3"}, {"k2", "v4"} } },
                      { "value3", { {"k1", "v1"}, {"k2", "v5"} } } };

  //First we set-up a predicate lambda                                                                                                                                                                      
  auto printIfKeyValueFound = [](const myMap& tab, const elemType& query) {
                                // O(n) for the first table and O(1) lookup for each, O(n) total                                                                                                           
                                 for(const auto& el : tab) {
                                   auto it = el.second.find(query.first);
                                   if(it != el.second.end()) {
                                     if(it->second == query.second) {
                                       std::cout << "Element found: " << el.first << "\n";
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                 };

  auto query = elemType{"k1", "v1"};

  printIfKeyValueFound(table, query);
```

> Output: Value3, Value1

For queries of arbitrary size you can:

```
//First we set-up a predicate lambda                                                                                                                                                                      
auto printIfKeyValueFound = [](const myMap& tab, const std::vector<elemType>& query) {
                               // O(n) for the first table and O(n) for the query O(1) search                                                                                                             
                               // O(n^2) total                                                                                                                                                            
                               for(const auto& el : tab) {
                                 bool found = true;
                                 for(const auto& queryEl : query) {
                                   auto it = el.second.find(queryEl.first);
                                   if(it != el.second.end() && it->second != queryEl.second) {
                                       found = false;
                                       break;
                                   }
                                 }
                                 if(found)
                                   std::cout << el.first << "\n";
                                 }
                              };


auto query = std::vector<elemType>{ {"k1", "v1"}, {"k2", "v2"} };
```

> output Value1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189257/discussion-on-answer-by-kostasrim-partial-lookup-in-key-value-map-where-key-itse).